# Given a point on a graph that has two possible values for its constant. How do I work it out?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Unsure of exactly how to go about finding the values for $k$ in this question:

The point $A$ has coordinates $(-1,2)$ and the point $B$ has coordinates $(3,-5)$.
   The point $C$ has coordinates $(k,2k + 3)$.
Given that the distance from $A$ to $C$ is $\sqrt{13}$, find the two possible values of the constant $k$.

I've started of using Pythagorus' theorem
$$AB^2 = BC^2 + AC^2 \\
=(-1-3)^2 + (2-(-5))^2 \\
= 16 + 49$$
$$\therefore\sqrt{{AB}^2} = \sqrt{65} \\
\therefore AB = \sqrt{13}\sqrt5$$

How do I got about finding the values of $k$? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why is $B$ involved at all?  The distance from $A$ to $C$ does not involve $B$.  Or did you mean something like "the distance from $C$ to the line connecting $A,B$?

Comment: When I first saw the question I assumed the C was to do with Pythagorus' Theorem because that is usually how the new point is denoted when using a new point to find the length of the hypotenuse (AB) so I started by just working out the coordinates of C and the distance of AB. Now I think its got nothing to do with Pythagorus but I am still non the wiser of how to go about answering the question.

Comment: Nowhere does it say that $\Delta ABC$ is a right triangle.  I'd say just use the distance formula:  $13=(-1-k)^2+(2-(2k+3))^2$.  Quadratic in $k$.

Answer (score 1):

**Why** did you calculate the distance from $A$ to $B$??  The problem, "Given that the distance from $A$ to $C$ is \sqrt{13}, find the two possible values of the constant $k$." says nothing at all about $B$.  $A= (-1, 2)$ and $C= (k, 2k+3)$.  The square of the distance between $A$ and $C$ is $(k-(-1))^2+ (2k+ 3- 1)^2= 13$.  That is equivalent to $k^2+ 2k+ 1+ 4k^2+ 8k+ 4= 5k^2+ 10k+ 5= 13$.  Solve that equation for $k$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer makes much more sense now. The previous question was related to pythag so I wrongly assumed this might have been something to do with it because I couldn't make sense of the question at first. Just one last thing on the last line of your answer where did you get 9k^2 from? Thanks

Comment: Note:  there is a small algebraic error here.  the distance formula ought to yield $(k-(-1))^2+(2k+3-2)^2=13$.

Comment: I've got an answer for k now of either k=1 or k= -2.2 do you know if that is right? Thanks @lulu

Comment: I got the same values you did.

Comment: Great thats a relief. Thanks for the help.